# My program doesn't require me to import external css

Tags: reactjs

In my project I'm adding CSS to certain components using className = "" and referring to external CSS names. They work, but the strange this is that when I remove the "import './styling/home.css'; it still applies the style.

I'm asking this because when my project gets bigger I might want to name some css by the same name and I don't want it applying the wrong one.

```
 import './styling/home.css';
```

The files are arranged as such

-HomeComponents.js

-AppComponents.js

-styling

.. -home.css

..   -app.css

Comment: The CSS is being imported some other way. We'd have to see all of the relevant files to make an accurate determination. Likely, the css file is being referenced as a stylesheet in index.html or it's part of a template file that's being used that you forgot about.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to "name some css by the same name" you must use scoped styling. To do so, you should use module css. Here is the create-react-app documentation for this
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

You might have imported the `home.css` in `index.js` that's why it got applied to whole project. try removing it from there and see the change.